# php url encode and htaccess parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, urlencode

I have encoded my url text (ex: Ice's Bird) and pass it as a parameter to another file via htaccess redirection and the url appears as below.

http://test.com/nature-pic-Ice%26%23039%3Bs_bird.php

In the above url, I want the word Ice's bird as parameter, but I can get only the word before single quote, ex: Ice

My redirection code is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/nature-pic-(.*).php
RewriteRule ^nature-pic-(.*)\.php content.php?tpath=$1 [L]
```

How can I get the full word from the url?

Comment: Do you have a lots of these name using a single quote?

Comment: yes i have several names

Answer (score 0):

this should be your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^nature-pic-(.*).php test.php?tpath=$1 [L]
```

fully tested with this address nature-pic-Ice's_bird.php hope it will help

Comment: I have used the same redirection as you mentioned. But the word after the single quote is terminated.

Comment: this is odd because this is the print_r($_GET); of the page i reffed him to Array ( [tpath] => Ice's_bird )

Comment: also notice that i removed the \ before the .php

Comment: By removing the \, it shows the following 404 error. The requested URL /nature-pic-Ice&#039;s_bird.php was not found on this server.

Comment: i added to the answer my full .htaccess as i used it is rwrite module is on by your apache ?